# CSS - top property only work from parent tag

Tags: css

we have two tag like this

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

and we have some CSS code like this

```
#parent{
    position:absolute;
}
#child{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:30px;
}
```

My problem is with `#child` tag I want `#child top:` and `left:`  set from body tag 
but `left:` and `top:` will set from `#child` parent tag

Note: I cant edit `#parent` position css property

Comment: You can't. The element with position absolute is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element, in this case #parent.

Answer (score 0):

position: absolute; allows you to position the element relatively to the first non static parent. So you need to remove the position: absolute form the parent and add position: relative to . If you can't then you should not use position: absolute on the child, but position: fixed, which will position it regarding to the browser itself.